# Como fazer download de um arquivo de release do GitHub usando WebClient em .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, github, webclient

Depois de minha pergunta de [Criar arquivos Zip e descompactar usando .NET 3.5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/510561/criar-arquivos-zip-e-descompactar-usando-net-3-5) eu estou com um problema. É que antes eu conseguia fazer o download de meu arquivo numa release do GitHub, só que depois não funcionava mais.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Reflection;

namespace IEIPInstaller
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        private string temp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "IEIPInst");
        private string localProg = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        public Main()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(temp))
            {
                if(File.Exists(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"))
                {
                    File.Delete(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip");
                }
                Directory.Delete(temp);
            }
            if(File.Exists(localProg + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Installer cannot be initialized because you have IEIP with this program.", "IEIPInst", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
            }
        }

        private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Directory.Delete(temp, true);
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnYes.Enabled = false;
            btnNo.Enabled = false;
            lblWant.Text = "";
            Complete.Text = "Status: Connecting...";
            startDownload();
        }

        private void startDownload()
        {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
            
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://github.com/JPPlaysGamer/IndustriesExes.Inc/releases/download/ieip-pre2/IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"), temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip");

                

        }
        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
                double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
                double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
                Mbs.Text = (bytesIn / 1024 / 1024).ToString("F2") + " / " + (totalBytes / 1024/ 1024).ToString("F2") + " Mb";
                Complete.Text = "Status: Downloading...";
                IEIPProgress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
                this.Text = "IEIP Installer - " + IEIPProgress.Value + "%";
                
            });
        }
        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                if(File.Exists(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"))
                {
                    File.Move(temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip",  localProg + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip");
                }
                
                Complete.Text = "Status: Completed";
                
                btnNo.Text = "Exit";
                btnNo.Enabled = true;
                
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Esse é o código de antes e esse é a URL do arquivo:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://github.com/JPPlaysGamer/IndustriesExes.Inc/releases/download/ieip-pre2/IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip"), temp + "\\IEIPv0.2-alpha-Windows.zip");
```

Eu troquei DownloadFileAsync para DownloadFile como a função Async tem thread separada da main e recebo esta exceção:
System.Net.WebException: A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio. ---> System.IO.IOException: EOF inesperado ou 0 bytes recebidos do fluxo de transporte.

Eu fiz tudo certo mas agora não funciona mais. Alguém poderia me explicar sobre isso?

Answer (score 0):

Eu descobri o problema, como eu uso o .NET 3.5, não há suporte a TLS e já que mudei para a versão 4.5 funcionou.

Pode ser também que o GitHub talvez usasse conexão TLS e não ter funcionado. Existe uma versão do .NET 3.5 que tem suporte a TLS e vi que funcionou. Pode funcionar também com `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` adicionando SSl3, TLS, TLS11, TLS12 e TLS13 mas no .NET 3.5 não tem TLS11, TLS12 e TLS13.